# Mongoose populate query and unwrap the objects to obtain an array of strings

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following query with mongoose:

```
const user = await this.userModule.findById(id).populate('roles', 'label -_id');
```

The output will look like this:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("61e2bc757644758d31578c7d"),
  email: 'hehehe@hehe.com',
  roles: [ { label: 'basic' }, { label: 'admin' } ]
}
```

My question is if there is a way to achieve something like this:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("61e2bc757644758d31578c7d"),
  email: 'hehehe@hehe.com',
  roles: [ 'basic', 'admin']
}
```

I want to get the value of each `label` property and add it to the `roles` array instead of adding an object like `{label: basic}`